# Как сделать так, чтобы контекстное меню Maui ListView получил объект по щёлкнутой ячейке

Tags: c#, listview, maui, menuitem

```
 <ListView x:Name="TodoList" ItemSelected="TodoList_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="16" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Data}" FontSize="14" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Удалить" Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked" "/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
        </ListView>
```

Мне надо получить ячейку из ListView по которой кликнули правой кнопкой мыши

Comment: Прибиндить SelectedItem?

Comment: Это не mvvm проект

Comment: Привязки данных не имеют никакого отношения к mvvm

Comment: Оно не выделяется если щелкнуть пкм по ячейке

Comment: Ок, а если Flyout повесить не на ListView, а на его строку? То есть расположить внутри DataTemplate?

Comment: Я так и сделал.

Comment: Что дальше делать?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.ContextFlyout?view=winrt-20348#examples выдернуть target в обработчике клика

Comment: Это не то и у меня проект на MAUI,а не UWP и мне нужно получить обьект ячейки ListView